# jQuery - triggering event instead of setting it up

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have list of image links, and want to code a button that is activating onClick event on that links. So:

'Without button clicked'  : clicking on link redirect us
'After button is clicked' : clicking on link bring us an edit dialog

java script: ('#settings-ico' is the button)

```
eventsHandler       : function() {

    var self = this;

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  *

    $("#settings-ico").on("click", function() {

        $(".b-row > a").on("click", tileOpenDialog( event ) );
    });

    $("#tile-edit-save").on("click", tileEditSave() );

    // - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  *

    function tileOpenDialog( event ) {

        event.preventDefault();
        let id = $(this).prop("id");
        this.editId = id;
        $( "#tile-edit" ).css("display", "block");
        console.log(id + ' click');
        alert(self.pageList);
    }
    function tileEditSave() {}
}
```

The button is "#settings-ico", and clicking it is bringing me my edit dialog immediately without clicking on any of the links.

`$( "#tile-edit" ).css("display", "block");`

but what I want, is to show this dialog, after some of the links being clicked:

```
$(".b-row > a").on("click", tileOpenDialog( event ) );
```

How to code this ? Why is the 'titleOpenDialog()' triggering after the button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling functions when you pass them as callbacks. Unless they're returning another function I guess. You're doing:

```
$(".b-row > a").on("click", tileOpenDialog( event ) );
```

When you should be doing:

```
// Passing in the named function so that it can be called
// later once the button is clicked
$(".b-row > a").on("click", tileOpenDialog);
```

Or if you want to pass in the event object explicitly you could do:

```
// Creating and passing in an anonymous function that will be
// called later once the button is clicked, which will in turn
// call the inner function.
$(".b-row > a").on("click", function(event) {
  tileOpenDialog( event ) 
});
```

As an explanation on what is happening when you click `#settings-ico`, basically once you click that it is running the jQuery function to select `.b-row > a`. Then it runs the `.on()` method on the return value and passes in a String `"click"`, and then it runs into `tileOpenDialog( event )`. Since there are parenthesis after it, the JavaScript engine must first run that function (which is why the dialog opens) then it passes in the return value (`undefined`) as the second argument to `.on()`.

Comment: thanks, it's working now. About the event object, I just read there's no need to pass it, jQuery is passing it automatically.

Comment: No problem. Glad I was able to help.